# Black screen with the cursor blinking (flashing)

Tags: installation, boot, lubuntu, screen

You might think this is duplicate, but it's not. I've searched all around the Internet and never found a solution.
I might be a total Linux newbie (although I've been using Ubuntu and Fedora for 3 years), but this just can't be normal.
 
I have this old PC, unknown chipset, unknown graphic card (I know it makes things harder). I only know it runs with a Pentium IV processor and 512mb of RAM. I decided to rescue that dinosaur in order to use it in my business place and install Lubuntu 13.10. Once it was running Ubuntu 10.10, but really slow (Window$ like).

When I installed 10.10, I had a lot of trouble installing with the live CD and alternate CD and DVD... the only one that worked for me was the minimal ISO. And yes, I've tried this [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) but anyway it didn't work. When updating to Lubuntu 13.10 (because LXDE is my one of my best shots), I had LOTS of trouble.

I used again the minimal CD and it worked after 10 times I tried. Once installed (I had never installed Lubuntu, so I went with "minimal installation"; and before in my virtual machine everything went great, even though I had to install LXDE manually because it booted as a terminal).

But my headacher old machine decided to cause more problems after install. Every time I boot, a blinking black screen comes out with the cursor.

Comment: You said you tried [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it). But there's a lot of information there. If you're still having this problem, I recommend expanding your question to explain in detail exactly what troubleshooting steps and attempted fixes you tried, and exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I have only been on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for around 12 months and it was my first time to Linux so I am definitely not an expert.

I understand this post is about 10.10 however my recent post for the same problem I was having in 12.04 LTS ([**One solution to black screen with flashing cursor on reboot in 12.04 LTS**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403877/one-solution-to-black-screen-with-flashing-cursor-on-reboot-in-12-04-lts))
may help as it ended up being an issue in the BIOS settings.

I'm not sure if your machine has the same "**USB device boot priority**" setting in the BIOS but it may be worth looking at or looking into the Boot Priority in the BIOS if you haven't already done so.

Brad.